# Does ShareLateX Have a limit in the number of characters?

Tags: sharelatex

I am using ShareLaTeX to write a scientific paper and I noticed that at some point it doesn't compile. I played around by commenting some piece of code and it seems that at some point I get it to compile.

The syntax is correct, so I am assuming it has to do with the number of characters in a `.tex` project.

COuld that be the case?

Comment: From sharelatex site: "Once out of beta we aim to always offer a fully featured free account. At the moment the only thing we are planning on limiting is the total number of projects." And they don't even limit number of projects. I can find no evidence to suggest there is a word limit. However, there is a compiling *time* limit, so I don't know if that has to do with it.

Comment: @heather Thanks for your comment! The document is quite simple I would say and doesn't even contain any figures so far! The weird is that if I comment out a few characters it works! Do you have any idea about the compilation time? Does it give you a specific error for instance?

Comment: I believe the compilation timeouts after one minute. Let me see if I can find the error...

Comment: [Here's a page](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Debugging_Compilation_timeout_errors) containing information on the sharelatex site. Do you have a lot of high-resolution images? That could slow it down.

Comment: @heather A minute? That's a lot!!! At the moment I have no images and the compilation is done in less that 2 seconds!

Comment: Oh, wow, I doubt that's the problem then.

Comment: Would you mind posting some of your code? I can't think of anything that wouldn't be an error, but you said the syntax is correct...does it give any errors? If so, please post those as well.

Comment: @heather Sure I will! http://pastebin.com/MuFFFtcS

Comment: Weird thing : I've sent them a question and at the moment I get the error `Server Error Sorry, something went wrong and your project could not be compiled. Please try again in a few moments.`

Comment: Okay, I do have one question, somewhat unrelated: how do you get the `webofc` package in sharelatex?

Comment: @heather I download it from this site ftp://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/web-conf/ and then I upload it in my project directory

Comment: I'm having some unfortunate errors. I uploaded the file but it's giving 42 different errors from the file, and I'm not sure why...probably something I did. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: Compile the problematic code on sharelatex and then check if the log-file contains any information.

Comment: @Thanos, I compiled your document fine offline(*not* using ShareLatex), with only a few warnings: `Over-specification in `v'-direction`, `Class webofc Warning: \sidecaption: No sufficient room for the legend`, `[3pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{figure.3}`.

Comment: Yeah, I have no clue what's wrong, but the webofc file isn't working, and so I can't compile the document. Sorry! I think I'm going to have to throw in the towel.

Comment: @Thanos, do you really want to write the names of 127 people on your titlepage? I understand this is really a team-effort, but I think it would be better to have that information somewhere else, and a bit more tidy, maybe a `table` or something. Also, don't use `\label{fig-1}`, write something more useful, and easier to remember, like `\label{fig:AwesomeTiger}`

Comment: @RunarTrollet : Yes, I have to write 127 names! It's the collaboration's policy! As far as the labels are concerned, they come from the template ;)

Comment: @Thanos, no problem, I hope you get an answer.

Comment: @Thanos, I just uploaded it to sharelatex, no errors: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/576dd1835f7e4afc1567f317

Comment: @RunarTrollet Be glad it's only 127. It could be much worse http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.191803 :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no character limit in ShareLaTeX. You could however be facing a timeout problem. In this case, the first thing you should do is to clear the cache on the project. This can be done by clicking the trash can icon at the bottom of the error logs window. If this does not work, then try some of the steps outlined [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Debugging_Compilation_timeout_errors).

Timeout errors such as these are usually caused by some mistake in the LaTeX code, such as a missing bracket, or a blank line in a \title{...} or \author{...} statement, though sometimes they can be caused by a very large amount of high resolution graphics or tikz images.

Comment: As stated in the comments, a timeout is not the issue here.

Comment: If you hit a size limit in ShareLaTeX you will get a message telling you so.